# Directory structure with Windows commands

Tags: windows, directory-listing

I would like to get a directory structure in Windows like the output of `dir /S`, but only line beginning like this: `Directory of...`

Comment: `dir /s /ad /b` or `tree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on `Directory of`, this might help (running from a command line):

```
for /f "delims==" %i in ('dir /s ^| find "Directory of"') do @echo %i
```

Running from a batch file, double the percentage:

```
@for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir /s ^| find "Directory of"') do @echo %%i
```